# How to add JS frameworks to use in the backend of SailsJS?

Tags: express, sails.js

I want to add Underscore JS to be used in the BackEnd so I can call _. functions from my Controllers. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to install the library you want to add with `npm install --save <libraryName>`.

Then, on top of your controller, before `module.exports = ...`, require this library:

```
var libraryName = require('<libraryName>');
```

That's it.

In case of Underscore.js it will be:

```
npm install --save underscore
```

then

```
var _ = require('underscore');
```

on top of your controller. After that you'll be able to use `_.`-functions anywhere in this file.

**UPDATE**

The answer by InternalFX makes perfect sense too. Sails.js indeed globalizes Lodash via `_`, and pretty much all the functionality of Underscore Lodash implements too, so in this case, that's right, you don't even have to do anything.

Comment: Keep in mind this may conflict since LoDash is assigned to "_" by default.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do anything.

Sails loads [LoDash](http://lodash.com) by default.

It is already assigned to "_".

So unless you need some very specific incompatibility between LoDash and underscore.... of which i don't know of.....your done.